# Updating values in a table based on the values from a different table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I apologize for my title being vague as I always have a difficult time describing what needs to be done when it comes to SQL. I am using microsoft access and I have a total of 3 tables: Credits, Orders, and Books which are shown below. I need to create an update query that updates the existing Number of Credits for each student based on the books that they have ordered and the corresponding amount of credits for each book.

For instance, student B-17 starts with 24 credits but after the update query it should change the student's credits to 32.

Credits Table

```
Student ID    Number of Credits
B-17          24
F-59          30
```

Orders Table

```
Student ID    Book ID
B-17          101
B-17          102
F-59          101
F-59          105
```

Books Table

```
Book ID    Book Title    Credits
101        English I     3
102        Accounting    5
105        Calculus      5
```

EDIT: I need to update the existing records, not change it to where it will update future orders.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this in a trigger, where the update is only accessing the orders that have just been added, (newly inserted orders), and not all orders previously added.

```
Update credits c set 
  credits = credits + 
    (Select sum(credits) from orders
     where student_id = c.student_Id)
```

Or, you need to flag each row in the orders table as to whether it has already been counted into the credits table.

```
 Update credits c set 
  credits = credits + 
    (Select sum(credits) from orders
     where student_id = c.student_Id 
        and added = 0)
```

and then set the flag to indicate that the order has been added.

```
 Update orders set added = 1 
 where added = 0
```

Comment: here you will end up adding it o every student as where is not specified for update statement

Comment: No, you will not, as subquery is what is called a "Correlated" sub-query. It outputs a different value for each row in outer query.

Comment: In this instance, however, I need it to update the previously placed orders.

Comment: @R.Bow - did you try the first query? Please advise if it meets needs.

Comment: @rBow, I thought, from your question, you were updating the `credits` table, not the `orders` table. And if you meant to say " "I need it to update the credits for previously placed orders", then why didn't you update those when the orders were placed? If you need to do this now, how will the processor know which previously placed orders have been already processed, and which have not? Clearly, some must have already been processed, or you would not be needing to increment the `credits. credits` column, you would just be setting it to an initial value.